# Where relation value higher than entity value with Eloquent

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have two entities; `Part` and `PartStock`. There is a one-to-one relationship between them:

**Part model:**

```
public function partStock()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\PartStock');
}
```

**PartStock model:**

```
public function part()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Part');
}
```

How can I write a global scope for `Part` that has a where filter for values on the `PartStock` relation and `Part` entity itself?

So basically:

```
$query->where('PartStock.count', '>', 'Part.reorder');
```

**parts table:**

```
`id`          int(10)
`category_id` int(10)
`description` varchar(255)
`value`       varchar(255)
`reorder`     int(10)
```

**part_stock table:**

```
`id`      int(10)
`part_id` int(10)
`count`   int(11)
```

I can not wrap my head around if it is even possible:

```
// here I have part reorder, but not the partstock count
$query->where(???, '>', 'reorder');

// here I have partstock count, but not the part reorder
$query->whereHas('partStock', function($q) {
    $q->where('count', '>', ???);
});
```

Can I in a way combine this two scopes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Eloquent: Querying Relations](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations).

```
Part::whereHas('PartStock', function ($query) {
        $query->whereRaw('PartStock.count > Part.reorder');
    })->get();
```

Comment: I see that my question was a bit unclear... What I want is to compare a value in the PartStock entity with a value on the Part entity. So basically; `partStock.count > part.reorder`

Comment: I can get it to work with join, but was hoping to do it with a global scope.

Comment: @hebron and how you would use this scope with this condition  `'PartStock.count', '>', 'Part.reorder'` (show plz abstract example with these two tables)?

Comment: That I am having a hard time figuring out to be honest, might be that there really is no way. Thanks for helping out, I have updated the question.

Comment: @hebron thinking, I found solution. See updated answer.

Comment: Hm, didn't think of that. Thanks, I'll give it a try this afternoon :)